Seaweedfs is not using new (empty) volume servers, why?
I have a seaweedfs cluster with 3 masters and 8 volume servers. Initially, I only had 5 volume servers. They almost reached the 90% treshold, so I added 3 more some days ago. But it is not using the new ones.

The /dir/status?pretty=y API returns something like this:
{
  "Topology": {
    "Max": 64,
    "Free": -260,
    "DataCenters": [
      {
        "Id": "dc01",
        "Racks": [
          {
            "Id": "rack1",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume01.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume01.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 64,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " 5 8-9 11 16 18-20 23 26 30 33 39-40 45-46 49-50 58 67 69 75-76 78 80-81 87-91 94 99 101-102 105-107 110 112-114 116-117 120-123 128 132-138 149-154 159 162"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "rack2",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume02.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume02.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 69,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " 1-4 7 10 14-17 21 26 28 30-31 34-35 37-39 42-43 45 48 51-53 57 61-63 65-66 70 80 85-86 89 91-92 94 96 99-100 103-105 109 111 114 117-120 122 125-126 129 132 139-144 155-156 160 162"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "rack3",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume03.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume03.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 62,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " 1-2 11 14 19 23-25 27-29 32 36 40-41 44 50 54-55 57-60 64 66 71-73 75 77 79 83-85 93 97 100 109 118-119 123-124 127 133-136 139-150 156-158"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "rack4",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume04.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume04.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 64,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " 5-9 12-13 17 20 22 24 32-36 41 43 46-47 51 54 56 59 62 64-65 67-68 70 73-74 76 78-79 81-83 86 90 93 95-98 108 111 115 121 124-131 151-154 159-161"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "rack5",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume05.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume05.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 65,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " 3-4 6 10 12-13 15 18 21-22 25 27 29 31 37-38 42 44 47-49 52-53 55-56 60-61 63 68-69 71-72 74 77 82 84 87-88 92 95 98 101-104 106-108 110 112-113 115-116 130-131 137-138 145-148 155 157-158 161"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "rack6",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume06.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume06.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 0,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " "
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "rack7",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume07.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume07.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 0,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " "
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Id": "rack8",
            "DataNodes": [
              {
                "Url": "volume08.intr.example.com:8080",
                "PublicUrl": "volume08.intr.example.com:8080",
                "Volumes": 0,
                "EcShards": 0,
                "Max": 8,
                "VolumeIds": " "
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Layouts": [
      {
        "replication": "010",
        "ttl": "",
        "writables": [
          72,
          146,
          27,
          158,
          60,
          84,
          148,
          157,
          44,
          77,
          71,
          145,
          147,
          25,
          29,
          55,
          119,
          103,
          139,
          155,
          100,
          57,
          4,
          10,
          109,
          143,
          38,
          21,
          28,
          85,
          1,
          104,
          142,
          52,
          66,
          61,
          48,
          53,
          140,
          37,
          92,
          42,
          31,
          15,
          141,
          144,
          2,
          3,
          63,
          118,
          14,
          156,
          80,
          117,
          133,
          134,
          105,
          120,
          89,
          138,
          18,
          122,
          149,
          113,
          101,
          162,
          26,
          69,
          110,
          135,
          107,
          23,
          94,
          99,
          39,
          16,
          58,
          19,
          91,
          112,
          137,
          75,
          132,
          50,
          150,
          106,
          30,
          123,
          136,
          40,
          87,
          88,
          102,
          114,
          45,
          49,
          11,
          116,
          24,
          35,
          51,
          115,
          108,
          70,
          81,
          13,
          160,
          159,
          97,
          93,
          47,
          12,
          131,
          22,
          95,
          154,
          33,
          34,
          5,
          78,
          96,
          125,
          151,
          20,
          82,
          111,
          152,
          62,
          9,
          65,
          76,
          98,
          124,
          153,
          6,
          68,
          8,
          36,
          59,
          7,
          86,
          126,
          127,
          130,
          161,
          73,
          83,
          90,
          46,
          64,
          67,
          74,
          121,
          128,
          129,
          43,
          54,
          17,
          41,
          32,
          56,
          79
        ],
        "collection": "",
        "diskType": "hdd"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Version": "30GB 3.64 b74e8082bac408138be99e128b8c28fd19eca7a6"
}

New files with 010 mode are always created on the old volume servers. I do not see any error message in the logs.
I'm affraid that when the old volumes reach the thresold and become read-only, then the whole cluster will become read only.
What is happening here? Is this normal behaviour? I want to make sure that the cluster won't become read only, not even for a second.

Old volumes went up to almost 90% usage and I did not want to risk going into read-only mode with the cluster. So I used the master server's "preallocate volumes" API, as described here:
https://github.com/seaweedfs/seaweedfs/wiki/Master-Server-API#pre-allocate-volumes
Example API call:
http://master.example.com:9333/vol/grow?replication=010&count=10&rack=rack6
The response was:
{
  "count": 20
}

and in fact it created 10 new volumes on rack6. Also, their replicas were created on the other two (previously unused) volume servers:

I'm not sure why it was adding new volumes to the old volume servers, and not using the new volume servers. New file ids are always allocated with replication=010 and nothing else given; so the file id allocation parameters were not preventing placement on the new servers. It might be because of some other internal placement strategy. For example, I know for a fact that the new servers have higher network latency... internal placement strategy is not described in the public documentation, so I'm not sure what was happening.
But at least, I was able to come up with an API call, and with that call I was able to test that the cluster will eventually use the new volume servers, and won't go into read-only mode.
